# Disabling the "Edit Filter" button on XTraGrid

Tags: c#, .net, xtragrid

How to disable "Edit Filter" button on XtraGrid? I want user to see the expression but do not want to edit it.

Thanks,
Omky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the web site [Edit Filter Button](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnViewOptionsFilter_AllowFilterEditortopic)

Just Set the `AllowFilterEditor = false` and that should suffice.